# Audio output and input stopped working after the last update

Tags: drivers, sound, 14.04, intel

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and everything was perfect until todays's update. Now my audio output (speakers) and input (microphone) stopped working. I guess it's a driver issue, but I need help to debug this problem and to solve it. I have a Dell Inspiron 5421 notebook with an Intel audio integrated sound card:

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

If I go to *Ubuntu Settings >> Sound >> Output*, it doesn't show my Intel card there anymore, it shows a **Dummy Output** instead:

[image: Ubuntu Settings >> Sound >> Output]

The same for the Input tab, it doesn's show my Intel card there anymore:

[image: Ubuntu Settings >> Sound >> Input]

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work! I'm not sure why, but I think the update removed my user from the group *pulse*. So, I added myself again and logged out:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G pulse renatov
```

When I logged back, audio was working again. If someone got trouble with the sound in this last update too, I hope it helps!

PS: Originally I added myself to *audio* and *pulse* groups. This update messed a lot of things here, I'll do a clean install.

Comment: Users should **not** be in the `audio` group: http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/07/13/top-five-wrong-ways-to-fix-your-audio/

Comment: But that worked... well, I'll just do a clean install.

Comment: The problem was an incompatibility between Ubuntu's official repositories and XORG Edgers PPA.